# Timestamp with search result

Tags: bash, shell, command-history, timestamps

I know that I can search history with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. Also I can
see timestamps like this:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%x %r '
```

then running the "history" command. However I would like to combine the two. I
would like to search using one of these or similar:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
- `history`
- `fc`
- `grep`
- `less`

but the result(s) should have the timestamp prepended. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
history | grep pattern
```

I also added this to my "~/.profile":

```
alias ahist='history | grep -i --color'
HISTIGNORE='ahist *'
```